# The using of visual studio compiler by cmd.exe + batch file

Tags: c, visual-studio, batch-file, cmd, compilation

Could you help me please with the using of visual studio compiler by cmd.exe + batch file?

I need to create batch file that will be executed in cmd.exe (C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe).
The body of .bat-script is:

```
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2017\Visual Studio Tools\VC\x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017.lnk" 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe" D:\temp\ctemplate\2\helloexample.c
```

Means I want to prepare command line with visual studio environment and then I want to compile file helloexample.c.

The shrtcut/link contains the target: %comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"

During the execution I see that only first line is handled.

The body of c-script is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> During the execution I see that only first line is handled.

If you want to run a batch file from another batch file you have to `call` it. Unlike an executable code run from a batch file, if you just run another batch file, the system does not return control to the calling batch file. That is why only first line is handled.

So add `call` to the first line of your batch file:

```
call "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2017\Visual Studio Tools\VC\x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017.lnk" 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe" D:\temp\ctemplate\2\helloexample.c
```